# Hide an action without disabling it

Tags: python, pyqt

I need to control my GUI with shortcuts, so I created some actions to assign the shortcuts. However, I have to put the actions in a menu (so they are visible) to enable them. And some of this action are very basic, like change tab, and don't deserve to appear in a menu.

Is there a way to hide them without disabling them ?

```
self.changeTabAction.setVisible(False)
```

This line hides the action, but disables it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it to your widget with `addAction`. It will be added to your widget but it wont be visible. Here is an example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        action = QtGui.QAction(self)
        action.setShortcut('Ctrl+t')
        action.triggered.connect(self.on_triggered)
        self.addAction(action)

    def on_triggered(self):
        print('triggered')

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Window()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```